# Which is correct: "higher distance" or "longer distance"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I would like to know which one of the two options in the title is correct: "high" or "long distance"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Normally "long" would be used.  But when talking of something like the durability of an auto tire, "high" may be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to the magnitude of the distance run and not the runner's height or altitude along the way.

Consider the pairs of words to describe the most and least of your item; a distance. While a "high or low" distance might be understood the better choice is a "longer or shorter" distance.

Comment: Or a larger or smaller distance.

Answer (score -1):

Distance is always considered in longer or shorter in fuzzy languages.

So, Longer is correct.